# Trying to use data()

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.solicitud_amistad').click(function(){
    var aux =  $(this);
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).data('receptor'));
    $.post('amistad/nueva' , {id_receptor:$(this).data('receptor')},
        function(response){
            aux.replaceWith(response)
        }
    );
});
```

and I'm getting this output:

```
<a class="solicitud_amistad" data-receptor="4">Enviar solicitud de amistad</a>
undefined
```

I expected a `4` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Your example works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/M7JjF/

Comment: You are using .data('receptor') but the key on the element is data-receptor?

Comment: works for me as well http://jsfiddle.net/qKuZq/ -- what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: are you using jQuery >= v 1.4.3 ?

Comment: could it be there is some other source for the error or a javascript error elsewhere in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery.data(this, 'receptor');
```

If that doesn't work then you are failing to set the data correctly and will need you to post where you store data against the key called receptor.